# Convergence test of sinus function

Tags: calculus

I'm to determine if the integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2+\sin x}{1+x^2} dx$$ is convergent or divergent. Is it correct to say that it is convergent because $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx \leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2+\sin x}{1+x^2}dx \leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{1+x^2}dx$$?

Comment: Noting that the integrand is non negative and the rightmost inequality above are sufficient.

Comment: Yes this is correct!

Comment: "Non negative" rather than "nonnegative" or "non-negative".  Second time in a few minutes I've seen that.  Is that somehow coming to be considered standard?

Comment: If the integral at all converges, it will be a real number. You have shown that this integral must lie between two real numbers, which proves the integral is a real number. Note that $\infty$ or $-\infty$ are not real numbers, though the real line may be extended to accommodate them. Anyway, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is ok except that I would explicitly mention that the function is everywhere non-negative or else that its absolute value is $\le 3/(1+x^2)$.  Preferably the former because it seems simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Though, you'll only need the right hand inequality; and you should mention that the integrand is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very formal yet (you are implicitely assuming that the integral has a value in the inequality). I would just say:

$$\frac{|2+\sin x|}{|1+x^2|}=\frac{2+\sin x}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{3}{1+x^2}$$
and $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{1+x^2}dx$$ is converging.

Comment: No the OP is not showing that. He/she is simply using the monotonicity property of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also you could write:
$$k\int_1^{\infty}\frac1{1+x^2}=k\arctan x\Bigg|_1^{\infty}=k(\pi/2-\pi/4)=k\pi/4$$
which is finite!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct because you show that $\int_1^\infty{\frac{2+\sin(x)}{1+x^2}}\,dx$ is greater and smaller than a real number (because  $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is integrable) therefore is real and therefore you have the integrability.